# Why doesn't the "ch" pronunciation rule occur for words such as "durch" and "manchmal"?

Tags: pronunciation

German has two different ways to realise *ch* phonetically:

One way (let's call this the hard realisation) like in *Kuchen*, *lachen* and *kochen* is similar to the Spanish *J*. I have learned that this pronounciation takes place whenever the *ch* is proceeded by one of the vowels *o*, *a* or *u*. (according to what Andrew website says [here](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/ujf/blog/German_ch.html).)

The other way (let's call this the soft realisation) like in *lächeln*, *frech*, *sicher*, *Küche*, *köcheln*, *räuchern*, *euch*, takes place when the *ch* occurs in the middle syllable or at the end of a word when it is proceeded by one of the vowels/diphthongs *ö*, *ä*, *ü*, *i*, *e*, *eu*, *äu*, *oi*. This realisation is similar (but different) to the english realisation of *sh*.

To my eye, *durch* and *manchmal* seem to be exceptions from these rules: There, the *ch* is proceeded by one of the vowels listed in the rule for the "hard" realisation of *ch* (*a* or *u* in these cases), but still the realisation of *ch* is "soft". Why does the *ch* pronunciation rule not occur for words such as *durch* and *manchmal*? Are the words *durch*, *manchmal* and *manche* that have the "soft" realisation of *ch*, exceptions from this rule? Is there any other exception for that?

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're asking about. Can you give some concrete examples (besides _sch_) when _ch_ is pronounced differently please?

Comment: That sounds completely wrong. English does not have the ch sound, both sh and kh would be wrong except in words like chameleon.

Comment: »ch« in Standard (German) German is basically never pronounced like “sh” in English, except for some regional accents (unless of course it’s part of »sch«).

Comment: dear @ infinitezero! you're right. it's not exactly "sh" in english, I know it only "sch", but I didn't find and copy the exact pronouncing symbol.

Comment: dear @infinitezero, here this educational website say that soft sh exists in English: (https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/ujf/blog/German_ch.html). But you say no?

Comment: "To make things worse for English speakers, the resulting sound has, in the most common cases, no English equivalent." Since no appropriate sound exists, it is advised to speak it as "sh" but not as emphasized. I am not aware of the soft sh sound occurring in Oxford English. And still, even a softly spoken sh is not the correct sound, though close.

Comment: dear @πάντα ῥεῖ! What kind of concrete examples? In first group "ch" is pronounced this way:  1- lächeln, euch, glücklich, etc. And in second group "ch" is pronounced this way: 2- lachen, machen, buch, etc. What about "ch" in "manchmal", "durch" and "manche" ?!

Comment: Dear @Armin and how the pronounciation of these is different from _durch_, _manchmal_, etc.? They're all the same.

Comment: dear  @πάντα ῥεῖ , thanks! I know that they (durch, manchmal, manche) have the same pronunciation! The question is why they don't follow the above rule of coming after "dark vowels" in German? And is there any other exception to the rule or not?

Comment: @Armin I still don't get it. May be improve your question with concrete examples (may be even audio samples) to clarify what you mean please. Also _dark vowel_ isn't a very clear term for me.

Comment: I edited the question to remove ambiguity. I wish others would do this, too, instead of just voting to close the question: Make some effort to understand the question and try to help in case the question could be put in a more understandable form.

Comment: I think the questioner put in the effort. I genuinely had no idea what the initial question was about. It is clearer now

Comment: @infinitezero yep _kh_ does indeed exist in English and is most used for transliteration of the sound ch gets in the German word lachen. For example when you see the name _Khaled_ in a German newspaper the journalists simply did not bother to use the proper (German) transliteration, which would be likely something like Chalid. Because the point of transliterations is to convey the pronunciation as understood by speakers of the "receiving" language. Kh appears to be commonly understood in that sense by English native speakers (I am not one).

Comment: I just saw this question a few minutes ago, but after a look to the version history I think - even though it was formulated a bit clumsy - it was quite clear what the OP meant and what was the basic misunderstanding that confused him.

Comment: "This realisation is similar (but different) to the english realisation of sh."

As you can read in Carsten S.'s answer and in various comments, it is not true for High German pronounciation. However, there are German dialects for which you are right. In Hessian and in and Palatinate German "ch" frequently is similar to the English "sh". This only happens for the variant [ç]. For example: "ich" sounds like "ish".

Comment: [x] in Great Britain: It does not exist in Englisch, but nevertless occurs in Scotland. An example is "Loch Ness". The correct pronounciation is of course Gaelic, but it seems to be quite common in Scotland. The "normal" English speaker says "Lock Ness".

Comment: There are also German dialects pronouncing "ort" at the end of a syllable as "o[x]t". Examples: dort -> doc[x]t, Wort -> Woc[x]t.

Comment: I think you are talking about the difference between what germans call "ich-laut" and "ach-laut". As a Dutch person, I never noticed that difference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your examples, the “ch” follows a consonant, the vowel before the consonant does not matter. After a consonant the pronunciation is like after a front vowel (like *e*).

And even though it was clear to me what you meant, the pronunciation of *ch* is rather different from English *sh*, and I am not even sure what pronunciation of English *kh* you had in mind.

Comment: dear @CarstenS, thanks for your description, I thought so, but in example like: "milch", also "ch" comes just after a consonant, but it would never pronounce like "durch", "manche" or "manchmal" !

Comment: @Armin https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53754/why-ch-pronunciation-rule-doesnt-occur-for-words-such-as-durch-manchmal?noredirect=1#comment130926_53754 You're wrong about that. These are all pronounced the same. Are you failing to hear that regarding idiomatic fallacies / exceptions?

Comment: This depends on dialect. For example, some Southern dialects realize *durch* as *du**a**ch* and the *ch* is the same as in *ach*.

Comment: dear @ πάντα ῥε, Thanks! So after consonant it always pronounce like soft "sh" in englich? and because of that "milch", "manchmal", "manche", "durch" have the same pronunciation?

Comment: The *r* itself is special. It's either a consonant or the **Tiefschwa** vowel in German. In *rch*, it's a Tiefschwa, and the amount of vowelness depends on dialect.

Comment: I think the confusion is about *ch* alone and *sch* if not within two syllables. If in one syllable, *sch* (*naschen*) is like English *sh*, otherwise *ch* alone (*durch*) or *s-ch* (*Häuschen*), it is like Spanish *j*.

Comment: @CarstenS: das Englische _kh_ wird häufig für die Transliteration des Frikativs [`[x​]`](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_IPA-Zeichen#X) (was also im Deutschen _ch_ wie in _lachen_ entspricht) benutzt. Beispiel [Khashoggi](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamal_Khashoggi), die _englische_ Transliteration des arabischen Namens. Der Name wird in etwa "Cha-schu-dschi" und nicht etwa "Ka-schoggi" ausgesprochen.

Comment: @0xC0000022L But how is "kh" pronounced in English? I doubt that many native speakers  can do that correctly as [x].

Comment: @0xC0000022L, Danke, das wusste ich nicht.

Comment: @PaulFrost having been a couch-surfing host and having seen first hand how certain English native speakers don't seem to make much of an effort to pronounce (foreign) names correctly (Ragnar becomes "ranger" and some other names become totally unintelligible), I think you are probably right with that assessment. Having seen that gave me a clue why Chinese who deal internationally pick Western names ...

Answer (score 8):

If [x] or [ç] has to be pronounced at the beginning of a syllable, it is always [ç]:

Mädchen [ˈmɛːtçən]

When it is not at the beginning, it is [x] only if it is immediately preceded by the sounds [a], [o], [ɔ], [u] or [ʊ].

In all other cases [ç] is the right choice. This does not only mean, that after the other vowels you have to use [ç], but also after all consonants.

(Note, that there are exceptions for swiss dialects, where [x] might beused when it has to be [ç] in standard German.)

---

**Vowels (monophthongs) before [x] or [ç]**

- [i] → [ç]
  Viech [fiːç] (umgangssprachlich für *Tier*)
  siech [ziːç] (veraltet: sterbenskrank)
- [ɪ] → [ç]
  ich [ɪç]
  mich [mɪç]
  völlig [ˈfœlɪç] (Note, That in most regions …ig at the end of a syllable is spoken as […ɪç])
  häufig [ˈhɔɪ̯fɪç]
- [e] → ?
  no examples found for [x] or [ç] after [e]
- [ɛ] → [ç]
  Gespräch [ɡəˈʃpʁɛːç]
  Pech [pɛç]
- [a] → [x]
  nach [naːx]
  Bach [bax]
  Schach [ʃax]
- [ɐ] → ?
  no examples found for [x] or [ç] after [ɐ]
- [o] → [x]
  hoch [hoːx]
- [ɔ] → [x]
  noch [nɔx]
  doch [dɔx]
  Koch [kɔx]
- [u] → [x]
  Buch [buːx]
  Fluch [fluːx]
- [ʊ] → [x]
  huch [hʊx] (Ausruf)
  Bruch [bʁʊx]
- [y] → [ç]
  Bücher [ˈbyːçɐ]
- [ʏ] → [ç]
  Küche [ˈkʏçə]
  schüchtern [ˈʃʏçtɐn]
- [ø] → [ç]
  höchst  [høːçst]
- [œ] → [ç]
  Köchin  [ˈkœçɪn]
  Töchter [ˈtœçtɐ]

**Diphthongs**

- [aɪ̯] → [ç]
  reich [ʁaɪ̯ç]
  Teich [taɪ̯ç]
  Laich [laɪ̯ç]
- [ɔɪ̯] → [ç]
  euch [ɔɪ̯ç]
  feucht [fɔɪ̯çt]
- [aʊ̯] → [x]
  auch [aʊ̯x]
  Bauch [baʊ̯x]

**Consonants**

- [l] → [ç]
  Dolch [dɔlç]
  Mulch [mʊlç]
- [n] → [ç]
  manche [ˈmançə]
- [ʁ] → [ç]
  Arche [ˈaʁçə]
  durch [dʊʁç]
  Furcht [fʊʁçt]
  Storch [ʃtɔʁç]

There seem to be no German words with consonants other than [l], [n] and [ʁ] before [x] or [ç] within the same syllable.

Comment: I have to correct your final remark. In German diminutives are formed by adding "chen" (or "lein", but that is irrelevant here) and this gives plenty of other examples: Stäbchen, Rädchen, ...

Comment: @PaulFrost: I was talking about sounds within the same syllable. *»…chen«* is a syllable that starts with ch, so there is **no** consonant before it. I edited my last sentence to make it more clear.

Comment: you are talking about written consonants. nut I all the time was talkin about spoken consonants. Btw.: C before ch: Zucchini (neither [ç] nor [x]), Saccharose (1. c is silent). H before ch: frühchristlich (not in same syllable), Fernsehchef (not in same syllable). Y before ch: Psyche, Triptychon, Bodycheck, Hobbychemiker (all: not in same syllable)

Comment: Thank you for clarification. But then you should delete "manche" and "Arche" from your list and replace them for example by "manchmal" and "Patriarch". Moreover it seems to me that most words containing a syllable *ending* with a consonant +  [ç] have declined forms in which the [ç] occurs at the beginning of  a new syllable which could be an explanation for its pronounciaton according to your Initial rule. For example: Dolch -> Dolche, Patriarch -> Patriarchen. Of course this cannot happen for prepositions, but the only example seems to be "durch".

Comment: @PaulFrost parse *Rä-dchen* or *Rädch-en*. The Gretchenfrage is how individual realisations influence the sonority pattern; *Grätsche* certainly has a *tsch*-sound, word final /d t/ are mostly not voiced or aspirated and thus indistinct anyway; *Hühnchen* is hard to conceive of as having a cluster *nch*, but *Mulch* works fine; *München* is not even diminutive but becomes *munich* anyway to separate the cluster; *Radischen*, *radish* shows a preference to cluster. I maintain there's no initial /x/. If you strongly segment, you have to posit an unwritten glottalstop, *'chen*, like *'Arbeit*.

Comment: ... which figures that it was originally plosive *-ken*, as it still is in *Köllsch* or *Hessisch* ("bisken"). Also cp. perhaps *Kaninchen*, *Karnickel*.

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker, I was surprised during my research how complicated ch-pronounciation can get. There are actually 5 different ways to pronounce ch in German!

The many dialects do not help, for example Swiss German replaces basically every ch with [x] or [χ]. I have even heard something like *Chemie* with [kχ] on a Swiss Youtube channel.

However I think I was able to condense what I found for standard German into a reasonably simple algorithm:

## Algorithm for determining ch-pronounciation

*Preparation:* Convert verbs to their base form (e. g. Du lachst. -> lachen; Machs gut! -> machen).

Then check the following cases, listed in descending priority:

1. **Exceptions and Proper Names**, for example:

   - *Chemie* or *China*: standard [ç], southern germany also [k], colloquially [ ​ʃ ]
   - *Chiemsee* (lake); *Chemnitz, Cham* (cities): [k]
   - Diminutive *-chen*: [ç]
   - ...
2. **Foreign Words**, for example:

   - French & Portugese: [​ ʃ ]
   - English & Spanish: [ t​ʃ ]
   - Italian & Greek: usually [k], in scholarly contexts may need to skip to next step
   - ...
3. **ch before s** is pronounced [k]
4. **ch after velar vocals (a, o, u, au)** is pronounced [x] or [χ]. No difference is made between the two.
5. **else** ch is pronounced [ç].

## Examples

- *Du wachst* is first converted to *wachen* (to guard). *Wachen* is no exception, no proper name, no foreign word, has no ch before s, but a velar *a* before the ch. Therefore the pronounciation of *du wachst* is [x] or [χ].
- *Du wachst* may also convert to *wachsen* (to wax). *Wachsen* is no exception, no proper name, no foreign word but has a ch before s. Therefore, with this meaning, *du wachst* is pronounced with [k].
- *Du wächst* converts to *wachsen* (to grow). The argument is the same as above in *wachsen* (to wax) and so pronounciation in *du wächst* is [k].
- *Durch* is not a verb and therefore need not be converted. It is no exception or proper name, not a foreign word, has no ch before s, has no ch after velar vocal and therefore is pronounced [ç].
- *Manchmal* follows the same pattern as *durch* and is therefore pronounced [ç].
- *Chöre* is a noun and need not be converted. It is not a listed exception or proper name, but is a foreign word as it derives from Greek *Chor*. Since *Chor* is probably not used in a scholarly context pronounciation is [k].
- *Gnocchi* is a noun and need not be converted. It is not a listed exception or proper name, but is a foreign word and derives from Italian. Since this is not a scholarly word, pronounciation with [k] is in order. Of course, the word should be pronounced [ˈɲɔkːi] to avoid upsetting your Italian friends ;)
- *Chip* is an English word and therefore pronounced with [ t​ʃ ].
- *Champignon* is a French word and should therefore be pronounced with [ ʃ ].
- *Bronchien* (part of the lungs) is a scholarly used Greek word and skips the step assigning [k] to Greek words. Since in *Bronchien* ch is not before s or after a velar vocal, it should be pronounced [ç].
- *Brachiosarus* is a scholarly Greek word. It skips the usual step for Greek words and defers to step 4, because the velar vocal *a* appears before the ch. Pronounciation therefore is [x] or [χ].
- *Autochen* (diminutive of *Auto*) is pronounced [ç] according to the diminutive exception in case 1.

## Sources

Main source for this was the German Wikipedia:

[Ch (Digraph)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch_(Digraph))

I tried to organize its info into a coherent and logical form.