# epenthetic /i/ in r, l, n + ch

Tags: pronunciation

As a follow-up to a question recently asked ([Why doesn't the "ch" pronunciation rule occur for words such as "durch" and "manchmal"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53754/why-doesnt-the-ch-pronunciation-rule-occur-for-words-such-as-durch-and-man)) , I was wondering about the possibility and the extension of epenthetic /i/ in this environment :

- durch /dʊʁiç/
- Milch /mɪliç/
- Storch /ʃtɔʁiç/
- manch /maniç/

Isn't the form *Munich* as *München* is known in many European languages related to this phenomenon?

How would such a pronunciation be perceived in relation to standard pronunciation?

Answer (score 5):

There is a document form 1158 where the name *"forum apud Munichen"* appears, which means *"market/forum at the monks".* So, *"Munichen"* is dativ plural of the Old High German word *munih* which means *monk* in English.

In German *Munichen* lost the *i* between *n* and *ch*, and *u* turned into *ü,* so we have today *München*. The *i* disappeared, because for German native speakers *Munchen/München* is **easyer** to pronounce than *Munichen/Münichen.* *München* comes smooth over the lips, while *Munichen* feels a little bit bumpy (maybe because it has one syllable more than *München*).

According to your theory *München* should be harder to pronounce than *Munichen*, but the development form *Munichen* to *München* confirmes, that the opposite is true.

So, the idea to insert an extra *i* in words, where *ch* is the second (or even third) part of a consonant cluster, seems very far-fetched to German native speakers. We German native speakers love consonant clusters, and German has lots of them. In German there is a word that contains of just one syllable, but it has 7 different sounds, only one of them a vowel, and we are very happy with it:

- Strumpf [ʃtʁʊmp͡f] (engl: stocking, sock)

Other examples are: *spritzt* [ʃpʁɪt͡st] and *springt* [ʃpʁɪŋt]
There is even the word *[Gstanzl](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gstanzl)* [ˈkʃtant͡sl̩] (some kind of Bavarian or Austrian folk song) which has 8 sounds, 7 of them being consonants.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm thinking of r, l, n + ch when "ch" is final so "chen" would not be concerned,  "Mönch" but not "München".  München I referred to as an aside, perhaps a manifestation of older i-insertion.

Comment: As I said: There never was an i-insertion, but an i-elimination.

Comment: To support Hubert's point: OHG [miluh](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=milch), [manac](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=manch), [duruh](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=durch). Note that forms such as *Milich* have survived in [some dialects](https://www.lagis-hessen.de/de/subjects/rsrec/sn/shwb/entry/Milch).

Comment: I would say that _springt_ is really just six sounds, as your IPA transliteration shows. And _Gstanzl_ is really two syllables, as your syllabic [l̩] shows.